# Vertx 4 does not block when calling sockjs handler

Tags: java, vert.x

we've migrated our application from vertx 3 to vertx 4. Originally when client and server negotiated the websocket contract the application esablished the websocked synchron. Now since we have vertx 4 in use it seems that the behavior is different. We can see this when we add a breakpoint in the sockjs handler than the client is trying to esablish other connection types instead of websocket like jsonp and so on. In the migration guide (https://vert-x3.github.io/vertx-4-migration-guide/index.html) they mentioned the following:

`The HttpServerRequest.upgrade() method has been removed. This method was synchronous. Use the new method HttpServerRequest.toWebSocket() instead. This new method is asynchronous.`

We assume this is the reason for this behavior. The problem ist that we have kind of race conditions in two of our features. Is there a way to prevent this behavior? Or is there anybody who has experience with this and know how to react her. I am looking forward to hear your answers.

Comment: There's no way to prevent this behavior. Upgrading is an asynchronous operation. You shall update your code to take it into account.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.